# Build a circuit to modify a printer's power supply

Tags: voltage, current

Can I in anyway build a simple circuit that would change the printers power supply to be able to power the printer in the photo?

I want to convert a 22V 455mA power supply output to 16V 500mA output to power the printer. How can I do it, and what components will I be needing?

[image: The power supply in question]

[image: The printers power input]

Comment: It would probably be cheaper to get a proper power supply made for the printer in question.

Comment: Just buy the appropriate power supply. You won't save any money or effort. Not to mention it won't even provide enough power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its appeaars that the printer requires two power supplies - 32 V at up to 375 mA, and 16 V at up to 500 mA, for a maximum power consumption of 20 Watts.

The HP supply you show is only rated for 10 Watts, so would be insufficent to power the printer.  It would also be impractical to modify it to provide the two voltages the printer requires, even if it could produce the required power.

Comment: Isn't it like an optional thing, like either 16V mode or 32V mode because when i saw the adapter online it had only the 32V pins in it and it also says Max 20W doesn't that imply maybe it can work on lower values?

Comment: @Omar It doesn't make sense for it to list 20W on the device itself  if it only uses one or the other since the power of one or the other is much less than 20W. Regarding your conflicting observations of the adapter you saw online, the problem is you don't actually know one way or the other and are basically just wishing for it to be the case. Building what you want to build is going to take a lot more money and time than just buying an appropriate supply so it's already not worth it even if you knew for sure would work, let alone right now when you don't know.

Comment: @omar different printers have different needs. Some have 32V 2 Amps and 12V 0.170 Amps standby on the same pin. Some only use a single voltage like the one your 22V supply goes to. Some have multiple voltages on different pins like what you want to power. It always changes.